# How to use a class from another package in java?

Tags: java

I am wondering how to use a class from another package

here's a file that inside the package project1

```
package project1;

class student{

    void print(){
        System.out.println("s");
    }

}

class teacher{
    void print(){
        System.out.println("t");
    }
}

public class Project1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

here's a file inside a the package project2

```
package project2;

import project1.student;

public class Project2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        student x = new student();
    }

}
```

but I am getting a error that student is not in public,

Am I importing the student class in a wrong way that I can't use the student class , or it's impossible to do this?

Comment: Use `public class student {...` and move the `teacher` and the `Project1` into separate files - there can be only one public class in each file.

Comment: The class should be public to access it outside the package.
`public class student`

Comment: You should just use "public" in front of your Student class. That is exactly what the error is saying

Comment: Cmon @vojta, he already has a public class in the classfile containing staudent class ...public class Project1 . That wouldnt be possible. You would need to define the student class in a separate class file and make it public, or either create a class with default access and place it in package 2 .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private

Comment: Also, use Java naming conventions. Eclipse already complained at you for not capitalizing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't have two main methods.

Try making the classes static so you can access them with Class.etc;

Or you could try creating a new object of each class (I think this is better).
Remove the second main method, only leave one.
And make this the first one:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Student student1 = new Student();
```

Now you can access the student class using this object with student1.Something.
Do the same for all classes except for the one containing the main method.
    }

Also make the classes start with a capital letter.

Comment: Also you will have to import the packages and make the classes public.

Answer (score 4):

Check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)

If a class doesn't have a modifier (`public`, `private`...) it uses the default modifier, that means the class can only be accessed from the same package.

In this [this table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) you will see easily:

## Access Levels

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass  World
public      Y       Y       Y         Y
protected   Y       Y       Y         N
no modifier Y       Y       N         N       // this is your class
private     Y       N       N         N
```

So **you need to declare `Student` class as public in a separated file**, or put `Project2` in the same package than `Student` and `Teacher`

```
public class student{   
    void print(){
        System.out.println("s");
    }   
}
```

Comment: No, he already has a public class in his classfile which contains student class.

Comment: and? class declarations are unique... OP will be able to see `Project1` from outside the package... but no `Student` or `Teacher`

Comment: @JordiCastilla I think what he's trying to say is that you can't have 2 public classes inside one java file..

Comment: ahhhh.... ok.... I didn't get that! added *you need to declare `Student` class as public in a separated file* to clarify.... thanks @KalyanChavali

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your class student has default modifier which restrict the access level upto same package(not accessible outside the package `project1` to package `project2`). You can have only one `public class` in one `java file`.

Try this:

1. Create new file `student.java` in the package `project1`
2. Create `public class student` in the said
       file

Answer (score 0):

you should declare your `Student` class as public, as follows:

```
public class student{

    void print(){
        System.out.println("s");
    }

}
```

Anyway,
having multiple classes, which are not inner classes, on the same file is a bad practice as per OOP development methodologies. It is also bad for maintenance, debugging, reusable components and modularity.

I suggest that you will also split the classes declaration into separate file (even if classes are small and simple)

Comment: No, he already has a public class in his classfile which contains student class.

Comment: @KalyanChavali -  but student is not an inner class of project1

Comment: But still you cannot have 2 public classes in a single classfile right ?

Comment: @KalyanChavali Stop being annoying and post an answer, if you really feel that all the other answers do not answer the question appropriately.

Comment: @KalyanChavali - having two (not inner) classes on the same file is also a bad practice. I will even add this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble with access modifiers.

Your `class student` is now `package private` (no modifier). Make it `public` to use outside the package

```
public class student{
 }
```

Read [accesscontrol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) For detail.